# ElasticSearch terms count returns wrong count

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a query that counts products by category. The first loop gets all child IDs together and gets counted, then it gets counted for each child ID separately. but if I sum each child it is not the same as the first query

query:

```
    const esProductCountResult: CountResponse = await client.count({
        index: 'products_' + department,
        query: {
            terms: {
                categories_ids: categories_ids
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(categories_ids,esProductCountResult);
```

console logs:

[ 90, 91, 92, 94 ] {
count: 732,
_shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 }
}

[ 90 ] {
count: 584,
_shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 }
}

[ 91 ] {
count: 83,
_shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 }
}

[ 92 ] {
count: 54,
_shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 }
}

[ 94 ] {
count: 49,
_shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 }
}

if you sum each child count you get 770. but the first query returns 732.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably due to the presence of products that belong to multiple categories, you could try with this query instead:

```
async function getTotalCountByCategories(categories_ids) {
    let totalCount = 0;

    for (const category_id of categories_ids) {
        const countResult = await client.count({
            index: 'products_' + department,
            query: {
                terms: {
                    categories_ids: [category_id]
                }
            }
        });

        totalCount += countResult.count;
    }

    return totalCount;
}

// Usage
const categories_ids = [90, 91, 92, 94];
const totalCount = await getTotalCountByCategories(categories_ids);
console.log(totalCount);
```

Comment: ahh ofc... how could i not think of this haha :). thanks